# ng new want to write to '/Users/USERNAME/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/aa/9a'

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli

I got this weird error, that if I want to create a new Angular app with the CLI, it is going to fail because of the write permission.
Here is the npm error log inside of the console.

```
npm ERR! path /Users/USERNAME/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/aa/9a
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/USERNAME/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/aa/9a'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/USERNAME/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/aa/9a'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/USERNAME/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/aa/9a'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -13,
npm ERR!     code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!     path: '/Users/USERNAME/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/aa/9a'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   isOperational: true,
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir ' +
npm ERR!     "'/Users/USERNAME/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/aa/9a'",
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/USERNAME/.npm/_cacache/index-v5/aa/9a',
npm ERR!   parent: 'AngularPortfolio'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/USERNAME/.npm/_logs/2019-05-29T20_08_02_308Z-debug.log
Package install failed, see above.
```

I couldn't figure out why and what is happening...

I'm using angular cli 8v but I got the same problem with minor versions. So I guess angular is not involved in that.

If I run the command with sudo, no probleme, but that doesn't seem right! Even with sudo I got a lot of error message like

```
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/USERNAME/Documents/Workspace/lol/node_modules/fsevents/build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/USERNAME/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/USERNAME/Documents/Workspace/lol/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node" "--module_name=fse" "--module_path=/Users/USERNAME/Documents/Workspace/lol/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64" "--napi_version=4" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v72"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/USERNAME/Documents/Workspace/lol/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v12.3.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /Users/USERNAME/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/USERNAME/Documents/Workspace/lol/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/USERNAME/Documents/Workspace/lol/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64 --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/USERNAME/Documents/Workspace/lol/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:200:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.6.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/USERNAME/Documents/Workspace/lol/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/USERNAME/Documents/Workspace/lol/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.3.1
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.12.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
```

```
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /Users/USERNAME/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/USERNAME/Documents/Workspace/lol/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/USERNAME/Documents/Workspace/lol/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64 --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)

> core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /Users/USERNAME/Documents/Workspace/lol/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
> node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"


> core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /Users/USERNAME/Documents/Workspace/lol/node_modules/karma/node_modules/core-js
> node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"


> @angular/cli@8.0.0 postinstall /Users/USERNAME/Documents/Workspace/lol/node_modules/@angular/cli
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 install: `node install`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

added 1010 packages from 1041 contributors and audited 19008 packages in 41.655s
found 0 vulnerabilities
```

I also got the problem with installing packages. npm install only works with sudo.
Node -v is 12
npm -v is 6.9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Give ownership to npm like this:

1. sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm
2. sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config

Answer (score 0):

The solution layed in my .npmrc. I don't know why, but there where the global prefix set to .npm...
Now there is no permission issues anymore!